# SD Card Not Responding To Command 0 In SPI Mode

Tags: spi, sd, logic-analyzer

I am attempting to communicate with an SD card in SPI mode. I am running at 133kHz. I first send a hundred or so clock pulses over the course of a millisecond with the chip select signal high. I then set it low and send the sequence `40 00 00 00 00 95`. By my understanding (from reading [this website](http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html)) the SD card should respond with `01`. However, this does not appear to be the case. To verify that what I think is happening is actually happening, I used a logic analyzer. Here are screenshots from that:
[image: Setup]

[image: Transaction]

I have tried swapping out the reader itself, and the sd card is brand new. What could I be missing?

Comment: Is it only your logic analyzer that is misconfigured or have you swapped MOSI/MISO? You should send data on MOSI, not MISO.

Comment: My bad, my logic analyzer was misconfigured.

Comment: I have also configured my microcontroller to have a pull-up on the MISO pin, as recommended by the same website.

Comment: I have just been informed that the SD card is actually 6 years old, and using another one yielded instant results ._.